# JS: How get the object with the most recently date

Tags: javascript

I am trying to retrieve the object with the most recent date, but I cannot. I tried with filters and a reducer but no luck. Does anyone know the best way to do it? (Javascript)

This is the object

```
const data = [{name:"test1", date:"2019-07-21T14:25:02.816Z"},{name:"test2", date:"2020-07-21T14:25:02.816Z"},{name:"test3", date:"2018-07-21T14:25:02.816Z"}]
```

Comment: `sort` the array. Note that timestamps are sortable as strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use sort if you want to mutate your array. But your idea of going with reduce is not bad either:

```
const mostRecentObject = data.reduce((prev, current) => prev ? prev.date < current.date ? current : prev : current, null)
```